# Button Code to download Salesforce Content Pack

Tags: visualforce, content

I have created a content pack of our Quotation Template Documents that I want users to be able to download from within the Quote Page Layout, preferably by a button.  I have done some very limited VF coding, but not sure how to do this one - I am sure it's fairly simple, can anyone assist?

Answer (score 1):

This may be help you.

visualForce code:-

```
       <apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="AllAttachmentsController">
    <h1>Link Farm: </h1>

    <apex:repeat value="{!attLinks}" var="ad">
        <li><a href="{!ad}">CLICK ME</a></li>
    </apex:repeat>
 </apex:page>
```

Controller:-

```
 public class AllAttachmentsController
  public List<Attachment> ATT {get;set;}
  public AllAttachmentsController (ApexPages.StandardController stdController) { }
  public List<String> getAttLinks() {
   Id caseid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
    List<String> attLinks = new List<String>();
    String strURL;
    String strResult ;
   ATT=[SELECT Id, Name FROM Attachment WHERE parentId = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id')];
   integer j = ATT.size();for(integer i=0; i<j; i++) {
  strURL= 'https://' + ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Host')+ '/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file='  + ATT[i].Id;
  attLinks.add(strURL);
 } return attLinks ;
 }
 }
```